# What is the role of capacitor of avalanche photodiode circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, photodiode

[image]

I got few questions about apd circuit.

There's a capacitor between the cathode and ground.

What is the role of this capacitor?

In picture, it say's 'min. 0.1uF, closest to APD', however, the capacitance of APD is 2.2pF, so it 's much smaller than 0.1uF, but the minimum value recommended is 0.1uF, so I got to use 0.1uF capacitor? Even it's not close to the capacitance of APD?

In addition, in case of calculating the RC time of this circuit, do I have to consider the capacitance of this additional capacitor?

Comment: "Closest" here means physically close. Mounted close to the photodiode on the PCB.

Comment: closer spatially

Comment: Please provide link to the circuit. There is probably other context information with it.

Answer (score 0):

First off: all APD's act like current sources when the lighth comes.

---

That capacitor, let's name it C, filters out the noise coming from the power supply.

The APD capacitande of 2.2 pF is not in parallel to that capacitor: it's in parallel to the APD itself.

The RC constant is meant for the power supply not for the APD.

The RC constant is anyway so big that any current signal, popping out of the APD, will "see" the cathode of the APD shounted to GND and will be directed to the readout resistor.